# kendo UI numeric textbox culture not translating correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using a numeric textbox on my MVC site that is bound to an object, like:

```
@Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m =>  m.Latitude).Decimals(8).Min(-90).Max(90).Step(.01)
```

Where the Latitude object is just a property that looks like:

```
public double? Latitude { get; set; }
```

my website can be shown in 2 different cultures, both getting it's data from the same database.  So the value saved in the database looks like '48.33900606', etc.  This all works fine on my en-US website, but on my de-DE website the value doesn't show up at all on edit.  If i type in '48,33900606', it works fine and i can save and it saves as a double like it should.  If i 'edit', where the numeric textbox loads with that value, it just blanks out.  If i click on the box, i can see '4833900606' without commas, without periods, but when i click away it changes to 90,00 (becuase that's my listed maximum above).  Anyway to reconcile this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the culture when you work in de-DE

Add to your page

```
 <script src="kendo.culture.de-DE.js"></script>
```

Set the culture

```
 kendo.culture("de-DE");
```

[Kendo reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/overview)

[Tutorial](http://www.macaalay.com/2014/02/14/adding-cultures-to-kendo-ui-project/)

**Update**

In that case, I'd suggest to format the number before sending it to the Kendo widget

```
<input id="txtLatitude" name="Latitude">
<script>
    $("#txtLatitude").kendoNumericTextBox({
        value: kendo.toString(Model.Latitude, "n8", "de-DE"),
        min: -90,
        max: 80,
        step: 0.01,
        decimals: 8
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have already done this.  For example, when i type in data into the numeric textbox on the de-DE site, 48.606... gives me nothing, but 48,606... DOES work, which i would think shows that it's working correctly.  The problem is only when the page is loading with data, with the latitude property filled in.  Then it doesn't show up correctly.

Comment: I updated my answer. I don't have a VS instance right now, maybe you'll need to add an @ before Model.Latitude

Comment: I do have an @ symbol before model.latitude, the entire control wouldn't work at all otherwise.  Additionally, i'm not using the javascript version of the numerictextbox, but the MVC wrapper, so your updated answer doesn't help either unless you're suggesting i completely abandon using mvc wrappers entirely

Comment: just started randomly working now, and i have no idea why because nothing changed.  I'm going to mark your response as the answer though because it's the best way to figure out how to get this working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Although the question is a bit old, it might work for some guys working with Kendo NumericTextbox on the latest browsers. You need to add the following code in the NumericTextbox declaration to override the type="numeric" attribute:

```
.HtmlAttributes( new { type="text" } )
```

I just found out that this happens due to the type attribute of the input values being validated by the browsers in some browser versions (I am getting this on Chrome 56.0.2924.87). This browser setting seems to mess up the values during validation and I get the same issue with the numeric textbox being blank

During the loading of the numerictextbox I get a console warning stating that:

> The specified value "5,00" is not a valid number. The value must match
>   to the following regular expression:
>   -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?